# WebClient is not successfully invoking "POST" operation

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am playing with Spring's *WebClient*. The primary implementation of the REST endpoints (in *DemoPOJORouter* and *DemoPOJOHandler*) seem to work. Also, the *http.Get* endpoint in *DemoClientRouter* and *DemoClientHandler* seems to work.

But, the *http.Post* for the DemoClient implementation "does nothing". It returns success (*200*), but nothing gets added to the dummy repo. I have a feeling that I need to do something in DemoClient to cause the *http.Post* endpoint in *DemoPOJOHandler* to actually execute (i.e., I believe neither the statements in *DemoPOJOService.add()* nor *DemoPOJORepo.add()* are being executed).

Based on prior pratfalls in WebFlux/reactive/functional efforts, I have a feeling that I'm not successfully subscribing, and so the statements never are invoked. But, I'm having difficulty identifying the "why".

Test code follows...

DemoClient router...

```
@Configuration
public class DemoClientRouter {

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> clientRoutes(DemoClientHandler requestHandler) {
        return nest(path("/v2"),
                nest(accept(APPLICATION_JSON),
                        RouterFunctions.route(RequestPredicates.GET("/DemoClient/{id}"), requestHandler::getById)
                                       .andRoute(RequestPredicates.POST("/DemoClient"), requestHandler::add)));
    }
}
```

DemoClient handler...

```
@Component
public class DemoClientHandler {

    public static final String PATH_VAR_ID = "id";

    @Autowired
    DemoClient demoClient;

    public Mono<ServerResponse> getById(ServerRequest request) {
        Mono<DemoPOJO> monoDemoPOJO;
        int            id;

        // short-circuit if bad request or invalid value for id
        id = getIdFromServerRequest(request);
        if (id < 1) {
            return ServerResponse.badRequest().build();
        }

        // non-blocking mechanism for either returning the Mono<DemoPOJO>
        //  or an empty response if Mono<Void> was returned by repo.getById()
        return demoClient.getById(id).flatMap(demoPOJO -> ServerResponse.ok()
                                                                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                                                        .body(Mono.just(demoPOJO), DemoPOJO.class))
                                                                        .switchIfEmpty(ServerResponse.notFound().build());
    }

    public Mono<ServerResponse> add(ServerRequest request) {
        return request.bodyToMono(DemoPOJO.class).doOnSuccess( demoPOJO -> demoClient.add(demoPOJO))
                                                     .then(ServerResponse.ok().build())
                                                 .onErrorResume(e -> simpleErrorReporter(e))
                                                 .switchIfEmpty(ServerResponse.badRequest().build());
    }

    private int getIdFromServerRequest(ServerRequest request) {
        Map<String, String> pathVariables = request.pathVariables();
        int                 id            = -1;

        // short-circuit if bad request
        //  should never happen, but if this method is ever called directly (vice via DemoPOJORouter)
        if ((pathVariables == null)
         || (!pathVariables.containsKey(PATH_VAR_ID))) {
            return id;
        }

        try {
            id = Integer.parseInt(pathVariables.get(PATH_VAR_ID));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // swallow the error, return value <0 to signal error
            id = -1;
        }
        return id;
    }

    private Mono<ServerResponse> simpleErrorReporter(Throwable e) {
        return ServerResponse.badRequest()
                             .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                             .syncBody(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

DemoClient impl...

```
@Component
public class DemoClient {

    private final WebClient client;

    public DemoClient() {
        client = WebClient.create();
    }

    public Mono<DemoPOJO> getById(int id) {
        return client.get().uri("http://localhost:8080/v2/DemoPOJO/" + id)
                           .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                           .exchange()
                           .flatMap(response -> response.bodyToMono(DemoPOJO.class));
    }

    public Mono<Boolean> add(DemoPOJO demoPOJO) {
        return client.post().uri("http://localhost:8080/v2/DemoPOJO")
                            .syncBody(demoPOJO)
                            .exchange()
                            .flatMap(response -> response.bodyToMono(Boolean.class));
    }
}
```

And, the DemoPOJO stuff, starting with *DemoPOJORouter*...

```
@Configuration
public class DemoPOJORouter {

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> demoPOJORoute(DemoPOJOHandler requestHandler) {
        return nest(path("/v2"),
                nest(accept(APPLICATION_JSON),
                        RouterFunctions.route(RequestPredicates.GET("/DemoPOJO/{id}"), requestHandler::getById)
                                       .andRoute(RequestPredicates.POST("/DemoPOJO"), requestHandler::add)));
    }
}
```

*DemoPOJOHandler*...

```
@Component
public class DemoPOJOHandler {

    public static final String PATH_VAR_ID = "id";

    @Autowired
    private DemoPOJOService service;

    public Mono<ServerResponse> getById(ServerRequest request) {
        Mono<DemoPOJO> monoDemoPOJO;
        int            id;

        // short-circuit if bad request or invalid value for id
        id = getIdFromServerRequest(request);
        if (id < 1) {
            return ServerResponse.badRequest().build();
        }

        // non-blocking mechanism for either returning the Mono<DemoPOJO>
        //  or an empty response if Mono<Void> was returned by repo.getById()
        return service.getById(id).flatMap(demoPOJO -> ServerResponse.ok()
                                                                     .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                                                     .body(Mono.just(demoPOJO), DemoPOJO.class))
                                  .switchIfEmpty(ServerResponse.notFound().build());
    }

    public Mono<ServerResponse> add(ServerRequest request) {
        return request.bodyToMono(DemoPOJO.class).doOnSuccess( demoPOJO -> service.add(demoPOJO))
                                                     .then(ServerResponse.ok().build())
                                                 .onErrorResume(e -> simpleErrorReporter(e))
                                                 .switchIfEmpty(ServerResponse.badRequest().build());
    }

    private int getIdFromServerRequest(ServerRequest request) {
        Map<String, String> pathVariables = request.pathVariables();
        int                 id            = -1;

        // short-circuit if bad request
        //  should never happen, but if this method is ever called directly (vice via DemoPOJORouter)
        if ((pathVariables == null)
         || (!pathVariables.containsKey(PATH_VAR_ID))) {
            return id;
        }

        try {
            id = Integer.parseInt(pathVariables.get(PATH_VAR_ID));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // swallow the exception, return illegal value to signal error
            id = -1;
        }
        return id;
    }

    private Mono<ServerResponse> simpleErrorReporter(Throwable e) {
        return ServerResponse.badRequest()
                             .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                             .syncBody(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

*DemoPOJOService*...

```
@Component
public class DemoPOJOService {

    @Autowired
    private DemoPOJORepo demoPOJORepo;

    public Mono<DemoPOJO> getById(int id) {
        DemoPOJO demoPOJO = demoPOJORepo.getById(id);

        return (demoPOJO == null) ? Mono.empty()
                                  : Mono.just(demoPOJO);
    }

    public Mono<Boolean> add(DemoPOJO demoPOJO) {
        return Mono.just(demoPOJORepo.add(demoPOJO));
    }
}
```

*DemoPOJORepo*...

```
@Component
public class DemoPOJORepo {

    private static final int NUM_OBJS = 5;

    private static DemoPOJORepo demoRepo = null;

    private Map<Integer, DemoPOJO> demoPOJOMap;

    private DemoPOJORepo() {
        initMap();
    }

    public static DemoPOJORepo getInstance() {
        if (demoRepo == null) {
            demoRepo = new DemoPOJORepo();
        }
        return demoRepo;
    }

    public DemoPOJO getById(int id) {
        return demoPOJOMap.get(id);
    }

    public boolean add(DemoPOJO demoPOJO) throws InvalidParameterException {
        // short-circuit on null pointer or duplicate id
        if (demoPOJO == null) {
            throw new InvalidParameterException("Add failed, null object detected...");
        } else if (demoPOJOMap.containsKey(demoPOJO.getId())) {
            throw new InvalidParameterException("Add failed, duplicate id detected...");
        }

        demoPOJOMap.put(demoPOJO.getId(), demoPOJO);
        // if the return statement is reached, then the new demoPOJO was added
        return true;
    }
}
```

Finally, *DemoPOJO*...

```
public class DemoPOJO {

    public static final String DEF_NAME = "DEFAULT NAME";
    public static final int DEF_VALUE = 99;

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int value;

    public DemoPOJO(int id) {
        this(id, DEF_NAME, DEF_VALUE);
    }

    public DemoPOJO(@JsonProperty("id") int id, @JsonProperty("name") String name, @JsonProperty("value") int value) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    /*
     * setters and getters go here
     */

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        builder.append(id);
        builder.append(" :: ");
        builder.append(name);
        builder.append(" :: ");
        builder.append(value);
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not edit the question to [invalidate existing answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290704/3956566).

Answer (score 1):

Here is probably your problem.

DemoPOJOHandler.class

```
request.bodyToMono(DemoPOJO.class).doOnSuccess(demoPOJO -> service.add(demoPOJO))
```

DemoPOJOService.class

```
public Mono<Boolean> add(DemoPOJO demoPOJO) {
    return Mono.just(demoPOJORepo.add(demoPOJO));
}
```

`doOnSuccess` returns `Void`, but you are calling a method that wraps the "action" in a returning `Mono`. So the `demoPOJORepo#add` function will never be triggered because you have broken the event chain here. The easiest fix is to just remove the wrapping `Mono` and return void.

```
public void add(DemoPOJO demoPOJO) {
    demoPOJORepo.add(demoPOJO);
}
```

Comment: Your response was somewhat helpful, but did not correct the behavior. I have revised my question and supporting code, taking your comments to heart, to try to better define/localize my issue.

The issue seems to be in the handoff between *DemoClient.add()* and *DemoPOJOHandler.add()*.

Comment: still hard `/v2/DemoPOJO` and `/v2/DemoClient/DemoPOJO`?

Comment: you are doing the same misstake ".doOnSuccess( demoPOJO -> demoClient.add(demoPOJO))" the `add` Function is returning a `Mono<Void>`. `doOnSuccess` takes a consumer, a non reactive function. A function that doesnt return a mono. A function that just returns `void` So you are breaking the chain here again.